# Pros and cons of whole project as a module?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana-3

I am in the process of learning Kohana 3. Just curious: some Kohana 3 projects I have looked at, like Kohanut CMS are implemented as one big module and located in /modules instead of /application (which is empty). Why is that? Only to make it easier to drag just one folder if you upgrade Kohana later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All depends what you are doing. I sometimes split different sections of my application into multiple modules. Usually its just for organization or if you want to use that piece on another application.

Comment: I can see if I, for example, develop a CMS and put some parts of the application as a module that is needed on some sites and isn't on others. But build the whole CMS as a module I can't see the point, I guess there is not real difference then.

Comment: Using CMS as a module allows you to change it without modifying original files. For example, you can create config files in APPPATH, extend classes using Kohana Cascade Filesystem.

Comment: Ah. I see. I think I get it. Thanks! :-)